# What's the power limit of c# language

Tags: c#

I'm a junior c# developer, and was wondering if there is any limitation for the language.

I mean of course only for windows operating systems, for example I know I can run my app as admin, create shared folders, shutdown the computer, open browsers, run exe and more.... all via c#

If some action can be done manually then can I conclude that it's possible via code?

Comment: It is effectively the "power limit" of the Windows API / kernel *restricted* to where/when .NET can run: ie. C# *can't* be used for drivers. Windows security is in full effect for C#/.NET execution, as with other executable.

Comment: The primary limitation of nearly all languages are going to be the ability and ingenuity of the person writing the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use API calls to native Windows functions in C# in addition to unmanaged code, so there's no limit to what you can accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Is it about the expressivity of c# (which can run on non windows OS too btw), or what can be done to the OS ? It's two different problems. For instance, you can manually reverse-engineer a binary, but to do so with unsupervised or non-guided c# program, it's not that accessible. c# won't do any better than any other language about uncalculable (not terminating) functions. c# is strongly typed, with all the good things it carries and the less good ones too. In the end, about what can be done to your system, it's more about the libraries you're using and the credentials than the language itself. c# libraries are well featured. To go further, you can still write a c# program that write assembly, and do "nasty" things to the kernel.